# Android proxy using sockets

Tags: android, sockets, proxy, stream, apache-commons

I'm trying to create a proxy in Android and I have to use sockets . I've read many tutorials and came up with following code. Unfortunately browser doesn't seem to get any data and after some time it displays standard web page saying that web page is not available. What might be the cause? Thanks for your help.

```
        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
            try {
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(9902, 0, InetAddress.getByName("localhost"));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    if (serverSocket != null) {
                while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                    try {
                        Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                        new Thread(new RunnableToReadSocketData(socket)).start();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

private class RunnableToReadSocketData implements Runnable {
        private final Socket clientSocket;

        public RunnableToReadSocketData(Socket socket) {
            this.clientSocket = socket;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Socket serverSocket = null;
            try {
                InputStream streamFromClient = clientSocket.getInputStream();
                PrintWriter streamToClient = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

                StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
                IOUtils.copy(streamFromClient, writer);
                String requestString = writer.toString();

                int firstSpace = requestString.indexOf(" ");
                int secondSpace = requestString.indexOf(" ", ++firstSpace);

                String url = requestString.substring(firstSpace, secondSpace);
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
                String urlWithoutProtocol = uri.getHost();

                System.out.println("==============Reading Socket==============\n" + clientSocket.toString() + "\n" + requestString);

                serverSocket = new Socket(urlWithoutProtocol, 80);

                PrintWriter streamToServer = new PrintWriter(serverSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
                streamToServer.write(requestString);
                streamToServer.flush();

                InputStream streamFromServer = serverSocket.getInputStream();
                StringWriter writerResponse = new StringWriter();
                IOUtils.copy(streamFromServer, writerResponse);
                String responseString = writerResponse.toString();

                System.out.println("==============RECEIVED==============\n" + serverSocket.toString() + "\n" + responseString);

                streamToClient.write(responseString);
                streamToClient.flush();

                streamToClient.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (serverSocket != null) {
                        serverSocket.close();
                    }

                    if (clientSocket != null) {
                        clientSocket.close();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're doing this wrong. After you process the CONNECT command you need to start two threads to copy bytes over the connection, one in each direction. Don't attempt to read the entire request before you send anything; ditto the response. Just copy bytes as you receive them.

When you read EOS on one socket, shutdown the other socket for output and exit that thread. If you've already shutdown the socket you read the EOS from, close both and exit the thread. You need this in case either end does a shutdown, to propagate it properly.

Comment: You don't need 2 threads to read and write data. One is sufficient. What above snippet lacks is proper request/response ending. I added combination of "\r" and "\n" at the end of request and response and between request/response headers because they were cut while processing. This caused messages to be successfully passed.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with previous.

The general principle is:

- Client connects
- Start reading thread
- Receive request
- Parse destination
- Open socket to destination
- Forward request
- For every Read on the destination socket, do a write on the client socket
- For every Read on client socket, do a write on destination socket
- If either socket closes (errors), close the other

So, two InputStream's, two OutputStreams, and just ferry data across them.

Comment: _General principal_ you're describing is preserved in code above. It will work equally fine if you: get whole request, send it to server, get whole response, pass it to client.